# Inserting data into database(sqlite) crashes my app

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Tried to call method from other class that returns data. However, it's either my app is going to crash or the data will be null

LOGIN CLASS:

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
public static String emailLogin;
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
emailRegister = findViewById(R.id.emailRegister);
```

when loginButton is clicked, it will get the text and use setEmailLogin()

```
loginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
emailLogin = emailRegister.getText().toString();
                setEmailLogin(emailLogin);
public String getEmailLogin() { //getting email
        return emailLogin;
    }
public void setEmailLogin(String emailLogin) {
        this.emailLogin = emailLogin;
    }
```

DB CLASS:
inserting data

```
public Boolean insertData(String email){
SQLiteDatabase DB = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
contentValues.put("email", email);
}
```

OTHER CLASS:

```
builder.setView(view).setTitle("Save Name").setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    //cancel
                    }}).setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                            Database database = new Database(getContext());
                            LoginActivity loginActivity = new LoginActivity();
//TRIED TO CALL GETMETHOD()
                                String email = loginActivity.getEmailLogin();
                                database.insertData(email);
    
                            }
                        }
                    });
```

LOGCAT:

```
    FATAL EXCEPTION: main 
Process: com.example.SoilScanner, PID: 10408 
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.text.Editable android.widget.EditText.getText()' on a null object reference 
at com.example.soilscanner.View.HomeFragment.getNitrogen(HomeFragment.java:51) 
at com.example.soilscanner.View.openDialog$1.onClick(openDialog.java:55) 
at androidx.appcompat.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:167) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930) 2024-03-10 10:24:08.957 2049-2606 InputDispatcher system_server E Window handle Window{cc5a17 u0 Application Error: com.example.SoilScanner} has no registered input channel 2024-03-10 10:24:08.977 2049-2370 InputDispatcher system_server E Window handle Window{cc5a17 u0 Application Error: com.example.SoilScanner} has no registered input channel
```

Comment: You have a null pointer exception but you haven't share the code where it happens. What makes you think it is related to the database?

Comment: Please put a breakpoint and inspect if the value of `emailRegister` in the `onClick()` method is `null`.